# ConTeXt xtable setup format of table head for all tables in document

Tags: tables, formatting, context, extreme-tables

Suppose I have the following table (one of many in a document):

```
\starttext
    \startxtable
        \startxtablehead
            \startxrow
                \startxcell Head\stopxcell
                \startxcell Head\stopxcell
                \startxcell Head\stopxcell
            \stopxrow
        \stopxtablehead
        \startxtablebody
            \startxrow
                \startxcell Cell\stopxcell
                \startxcell Cell\stopxcell
                \startxcell Cell\stopxcell
            \stopxrow
        \stopxtablebody
    \stopxtable
\stoptext
```

Now I want to change the formatting of every row within `\startxtablehead...\stopxtablehead` to a specific cell format, let's say something like

```
\setupxtable[head][background=color, backgroundcolor=gray]
```

I know I could basically tag every row within the table head of every table with `head` (in this example), but it seems a bit superfluous given that I have logically marked up the table head by the surrounding start/stop pair.

How can I pass formatting options to every row within the table head *of every table in the document*?

Comment: Just to mention that: I have searched the documentation but didn't even find all the options of  `\setupxtable`.

Comment: `\startxtablehead[head]`?

Comment: @TeXnician A list with (nearly) all options for the `\setuptable` command can be found in [setup-en.pdf](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/show-man-5.htm).

Comment: @Wolfgang Thanks. It's a good thing to know that what I ask for is not an option yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\startxtablehead` by itself does not apply a style, but is only relevant for page breaking with repeated headers.  However, if you tell it which style to use with `\startxtablehead[head]`, it will apply it to all rows in the header.

Here I use the compact syntax to save some space.

```
\setupxtable[head][background=color, backgroundcolor=gray]

\starttext
\startxtable
  \startxtablehead[head]
    \NC Head \NC Head \NC Head \NR
    \NC Head \NC Head \NC Head \NR
    \NC Head \NC Head \NC Head \NR
  \stopxtablehead
  \startxtablebody
    \NC Cell \NC Cell \NC Cell \NR
  \stopxtablebody
\stopxtable
\stoptext
```

[image]

---

As I said, `\startxtablehead` does not apply any style, but it is still possible to hack the macros to apply your chosen default style.  However, if you fail to define the defaults you'll see in the log for, e.g. `foot`

```
setup           > error in line 8, namespace 'xtable', key 'foot'
setup           > error in line 8, namespace 'xtable', key 'foot'
setup           > error in line 8, namespace 'xtable', key 'foot'
```

```
% macros=mkvi
\unprotect

\unexpanded\def\startxtablehead{\begingroup\c_tabl_x_mode\plusone  \dodoubleempty\tabl_x_start_partition[head]}
\unexpanded\def\startxtablefoot{\begingroup\c_tabl_x_mode\plustwo  \dodoubleempty\tabl_x_start_partition[foot]}
\unexpanded\def\startxtablenext{\begingroup\c_tabl_x_mode\plusthree\dodoubleempty\tabl_x_start_partition[next]}
\unexpanded\def\startxtablebody{\begingroup\c_tabl_x_mode\plusfour \dodoubleempty\tabl_x_start_partition[body]}

\unexpanded\def\tabl_x_start_partition[#defaults][#settings]%
  {\ifsecondargument
     \tabl_x_set_checked{#settings}%
   \else
     \tabl_x_set_checked{#defaults}%
   \fi}

\protect

\setupxtable[head][background=color,backgroundcolor=red]
\setupxtable[body][background=color,backgroundcolor=green]
\setupxtable[foot][background=color,backgroundcolor=blue]

\starttext
\startxtable
  \startxtablehead
    \NC Head \NC Head \NC Head \NR
  \stopxtablehead
  \startxtablebody
    \NC Cell \NC Cell \NC Cell \NR
  \stopxtablebody
  \startxtablefoot
    \NC Foot \NC Foot \NC Foot \NR
  \stopxtablefoot
\stopxtable
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I would have to repeat this for all tables in my document, don't I? Sorry, probably my question was quite unclear at that point. I am looking for a general setting for all tables in my document. Is there an option to pass this to all `\startxtablehead`?

Comment: @TeXnician Not without redefining `\startxtablehead`.

Comment: Not even with Lua? In LuaLaTeX such processing seems simple, but I cannot find anything on that with ConTeXt (as callbacks are disabled).

Comment: @TeXnician You can hack the macros, see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. This looks great (exactly what I looked for). Unfortunately, your second example does not compile for me (ConTeXt with LuaTeX 1.07 from TeX Live 2018) with the error: "Parameters must be numbered consecutively". Changing `#defaults` and `#settings` to `#1` and `#2` solved this, so I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @TeXnician Oops, sorry, I forgot to add the `% macros=mkvi` directive in the first line because I always save my ConTeXt source files with `.mkvi` extension which automatically enables MKVI macros.